# convert digit into string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a number which represent time and I need to convert this number into string.

Like n = 800 , it represent time = 8:00

Currently I am doing this:

```
n = 800;
string time = '' +  n/100 + ' : ' + n % 100  ;
```

but `time` become `8 : 0` but I want to minutes in two digit format like `8 : 00`
Anybody please help me there?

Comment: So 8:15 am would be represented as "815"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var n = 800;    
var hours = Math.floor(n/100);
var minutes = ('0' + (n%100)).slice(-2);
var time = hours + ':' + minutes;
```

Note the rounding on hours as well, otherwise you could end up with something like "8.56:56".

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do here is insert a colon before the last two digits you can just do a string replace:

```
var time = ("" + n).replace(/(\d\d)$/,":$1");
```

Or slice out the hours and minutes and concatenate with a colon:

```
var time = "" + n;
time = time.slice(0,-2) + ":" + time.slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shortcut solution :P

```
var a = 800;
var b = a.toString();
var first = b.replace(b.substring(b.length - 2),":"+b.substring(b.length - 2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pfhyhhg/